# Qt QString toInt() fails

Tags: c++, qstring

I have a 'QString' containing "-3.5", however if I try to convert this to an integer using the 'toInt' method it returns 0.  Why?

```
    QString strTest = "-3.5";
    int intTest = strTest.toInt();

    qDebug() << intTest;
```

intTest will be 0 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As opposed to [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and streams from the standard library, Qt strings require the whole string to be a valid integer to perform the conversion. You could use `toDouble` instead as a workaround.

You should also use the optional `ok` parameter to check for errors:

```
QString strTest = "-3.5";
book ok;
int intTest = strTest.toInt(&ok);
if(ok) {
    qDebug() << intTest;
} else {
    qDebug() << "failed to read the string";
}
```

Comment: But it is a valid integer, a signed integer is -32767 to 32768.

Comment: No. It's a valid floating point/real number. An integer has a discrete value.

Comment: ok, I can see that, but I would have expected it to truncate the result and return -3.

Comment: And that's what standard streams and `std::stoi` do. But not QString apparently.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toInt), it says

> Returns 0 if the conversion fails.

You should use

```
bool ok;
strTest.toInt(&ok);
```

and then check the value of `ok` - otherwise, you won't be sure if the 0 is the actual value, or an indication of failure.

In this case it's failing because it is not actually an integer (it has a decimal point). Note that you can use [`toDouble`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toDouble) (and check `ok` there too!), and then cast the result as you see fit.

```
QString strTest = "-3.5";

bool ok;
double t = strTest.toDouble(&ok);

if(ok)
    qDebug() << static_cast<int>(t);
```